# Can I teleport mobs to players view direction?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a mob follow a player, on their left in 1.9. So, whichever direction they look, the mob will be teleported to stay on their left. Here are the commands I have to teleport to the player.

Repeated block, then chain block.

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand] @p
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand] ~1 ~-.5 ~ ~90 ~
```

[image]

What do I need to do to teleport the mob to the left side of the screen always?

Answer (score -3):

[Directon based](https://youtu.be/yw_hr00tQx0) 
you can modify the commands resulted from the filter and make them tp them on left side

Comment: You've linked to a Youtube video to explain your answer.  I'm afraid you should summarize the information from the video, just in case it ever gets removed.  That way, your answer is still valid.  Besides, it also saves people a click!

Comment: How do I get it to work with ArmorStands?

Comment: I linked the video where filter is in description. Take the rotation selectors and for every rotation tp relatively.